# retweet count for a list of users

Tags: r, twitter, count

I have a list of twitter handles for which I want the retweets count. I am able to get it for a single handle but not able to compute for the whole list at once.

I am using this:

```
library(twitteR)
library(rtweet)
library(tidytext)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
library(RJSONIO)
library(stringr)

users <- read.csv("Twitter.csv")
users1 <- lookupUsers(users[2:5,1])

sample <- matrix(NA,1000,1)
for (i in 2:5) {
  sample[i,] <- sum(sapply(userTimeline(users[i,], n=5),
                           function(x) x$retweetCount))
}
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

How do i get it running? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: please include library calls, and if possible a reproducible example

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper i have called in these libraries : twitteR, rtweet, tidytext, httr, RCurl, plyr, stringr and RJSONIO.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper;  users <- read.csv("Twitter.csv")
users1 <- lookupUsers(users[2:5,1])                                                                            sample <- matrix(NA,1000,1)
for (i in 2:5) {
  sample[i,] <- sum(sapply(userTimeline(users[i,], n=5),function(x) x$retweetCount))
}

Comment: Thanks Rushabh Sunil Nahar, can you integrate those into your question text ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I am trying to edit but the edited version is not showing up for some reason